Shehecheyanu on Lulav during Kiddush on Sukkot night?
If the Lulav and Esrog were in sight while one recited Shehecheyanu during Kiddush at night, should he skip Shehecheyanu on the Lulav the next day?

At night isn't the zman for taking the 4 minim

@sam neither is the day before

Why would simply seeing the Arabs minim - not taking them - affect the obligation to say the Schehecheyanu bracha?

Whoever posted this was thinking of having the new fruit on the table on Rosh Hashana when making kiddush -- a shehechiyanu that will cover what you'll be eating in five minutes.

@shalom na, this is much better question

@EdwardB Shehechiyanu can be said already when making the lulav bundle, so the obligation is already there, ready and waiting.

@DoubleAA I do not know the answer to this. My confusion stems from wondering why simply having the arbah minim in sight without holding them when saying shehecheyanu in kiddush would affect the position with regard to shehecheyanu when taking the arbah minim on the morning of first day chag for the purpose of fulfilling the mitzvah of arbah minim

Firstly, if you don't have the intent to exempt the Arba Minim with the  Shehecheyanu during Kiddush then there's nothing to discuss. You would have to say  Shehecheyanu the next day before shaking them.
But even if you have intent while saying the Shehecheyanu during Kiddush, it seems it would not help.
It seems from the Poskim that there are 2 possible times to say  Shehecheyanu on the Arba Minim:

When you tie them. The Shulchan Aruch already makes it clear that we don't do that nowadays. Others say it's best not to tie one's own Arba Minim so as not to have to deal with this issue.
When you shake the Arba Minim. Preferably on the first day before you shake. If you forgot, then while you're still holding them. And if you forgot the first day you can say it on any of the 7 days before (or while) shaking them.

As the Mishna Brura says:

אלא בשעת נטילתו - אע"ג דמן הדין היה ראוי לברך שהחיינו תיכף בשעת עשיית הלולב (דהיינו בשעה שאוגדו) מ"מ אנן נהגינן להניח הברכה לכתחלה עד שעת נטילה. ועיין בח"א שכתב דאם לא בירך שהחיינו ביום א' יוכל לברך אפילו ביום ז' כשנוטל הלולב:‏

It would seem that any other time, you cannot fulfil your  Shehecheyanu obligation.

Why is this different to saying shehecheyanu on the sukkah while it is raining the first night (according to those who say you can't be yotzei sukkah then)? MB 639:36 points out that in such a case the shecheyanu still works for the sukkah

דאפילו אם נימא דפטור אז מסוכה מ"מ יוצא בזה דלא גריע ד"ז מאלו בירך שהחיינו בחול בשעת עשייה בסוכה דיוצא בזה

Also what happens if you say shehecheyanu when you first pick the lulav up, thinking that today might be 15th Tishrei, but it turns out that Elul actually had 30 days this year, so you actually said shehecheyanu on the lulav on the morning of 14th Tishrei?

-1 The position that there are only two times (making or taking) is that of R' Shmuel of Évreux and we don't paskin like him (Tur 662)

I'm guessing the intent thing is probably correct. If you had intent it probably would indeed work but there's no need so we don't bother.

"Others say it's best not to tie one's own Arba Minim so as not to have to deal with this issue." Who are these others?
